# Cross-Origin Resource sharing error: Header Disallowed by preflight response

Tags: python, reactjs, django, cors, django-cors-headers

i am learning how to use react as a front end and django as a backend. i am getting these cors issue everytime im hitting post method to django server. It is a very application. Sending a value from react to django server and printing it. In Django server terminal it shows  "OPTIONS /sample HTTP/1.1" 200 0
and in react it is showing cors error. i added all the different kinds but the problem still exists
`enter code here`

```
React Component Code
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import App from '../App';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "XCSRF-TOKEN";

class addProduct extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state  = {
        testId : '12324',
      }

    this.ButtonClicked = this.ButtonClicked.bind(this)
}
ButtonClicked =(e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(this.state)
  axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample',
        data: this.state.testId,
        crossDomain: true,
        mode : 'CORS',
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Max-Age" : "200"
          }
        
    })
    .then(Response => console.log(Response.data))
  }

   render() {
    
    return (
        <div className = "addProduct">

            <button  type = "submit" onClick = {this.ButtonClicked} >Start</button>
                   
        </div>
      )
    }
   }

 export default addProduct 



   Django Code:
   from django.shortcuts import render
   from django.http import HttpResponse
   # Create your views here.
  def showsample(request):
     username = request.POST.get('testId')

     print("the value is " ,username)

     return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

In the browser Network options it shows :

Requested url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request Headers:
with a warning symbol : Provisional headers are shown

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Referer: http://localhost:4200/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36

When  double click on the "sample" which is highlighted in red color.

Then the post request is passing and I can see the output on the Django terminal and HTTP Response of helloworld

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after struggling a lot.

I imported django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
and in the url pattern added this

urlpatterns = [

```
path('sample', csrf_exempt(views.showsample))
```

]

```
  from django.urls import path
  from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
  from . import views

  urlpatterns = [

       path('sample', csrf_exempt(views.showsample))
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with react and ajax and i tried to pass those headers with my request but didnt worked, i installed `Allow CORS` chrome extension which solved my problem.

In your case im not sure but try this two methods.

1. in your Django project `settings.py` file set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `"*"`. like this:

   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
2. install `Allow CORS` for chrome, or if you use any other browser there must be other cors related extensions for them too...

and if non of this helped please share the error you get, with us.